# VirtualStringTree.HotColor is not used with toHotTrack

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I added `toHotTrack` to `VST.TreeOptions.PaintOptions` and changed the `VST.Colors.HotColor` to `clGreen`, but the `HotColor` is not applied to the `HotNode` and only the text of the node is underlined.

1. How to solve this problem?
2. Is it possible to remove underline and only apply `HotColor` to it?

Comment: Do you have toUseExplorerTheme activated? Can you post a small sample project or describe how to replicate this with one of the VTV sample projects?

Comment: @JoachimMarder Thank you. I set the toUseExplorerTheme to true and now works, But the color of the node under mouse is not HotColor that I defined it in Colors. Why?

Comment: toExplorerTheme ignores most colors settings and tries to resemble Windows Explorer, that's why I was asking for it. Feel free to open a bug at the project homepage but please respect out guidelines for submitting bugs.

Comment: First, I hadn't active toUseExplorerTheme. I actived it after your first comment. Activing it causes to ignore most colors. Deactiving it causes to show hot node only with underlined caption. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

The `Colors.HotColor` is used to change the `Font.Color`, not the `Brush.Color`.
The use of `toHotTrack` only changes the `Font.Color` and adds `fsUnderLine` to `Font.Style`, see the implementation section.

```pascal
if (toHotTrack in FOptions.FPaintOptions) and (Node = FCurrentHotNode) then
begin
  if not (tsUseExplorerTheme in FStates) then
  begin
    Canvas.Font.Style := Canvas.Font.Style + [fsUnderline];
    Canvas.Font.Color := FColors.HotColor;
  end;
end;
```

However, it's quite easy to change, e.g. in `OnBeforeCellPaint`. If you don't want the `fsUnderline`, you need to remove `toHotTrack` from `TreeOptions.PaintOptions`, which is not needed in this case.

```pascal
procedure VSTBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; TargetCanvas: TCanvas;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; 
  CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
begin
  if (CellPaintMode = cpmPaint) and (Node = vstStrom.HotNode) then
  begin
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
  end;
end;
```